# Why are annotations added by checker framework needed at runtime?

Tags: java, checker-framework

I'm using Checker Framework via the maven-compiler-plugin. The resulting bytecode has annotations in fields such as `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull` or `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.UnknownKeyFor` that were not there in the source code. These qual annotations have `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.
My understanding is that checker framework [works at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68274013/1086540). Why are those annotations added to the bytecode then retained at runtime? is it standard practice to leave the annotations in production artefacts? because this means I will need to add qual to the runtime classpath, which sounds like an unnecessary cost/risk given that this is all about build time checks. Without that qual jar, libraries that introspect field annotations, like hibernate-validator, throw NPEs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(TypeAnnotationParser.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotatedType(Field.java:1177)
```

Comment: I feel like the question you're asking is really an implementation detail as to why the maintainers chose to keep their bytecode data in at runtime versus only having it at compile time, and we'd only be able to guess.  But I suppose it depends on their goals; given that there are different Java compilers out there (think javac vs Eclipse), maybe the *simplest* way to keep compatibility between the two was to retain the annotation data during runtime.

Comment: you are correct that i'm asking about the implementation detail, but usually those impl details follow a requirement (or maybe oversight?). i'm wondering if there's a feature I don't know about or if the problem is that artefacts with checker annotations are meant to be temporary and not deployed in PROD

Comment: No?  They could be using JNI for all we care and so long as it does what's advertised on the tin, it really doesn't matter *how* they do it.

Comment: @Makoto i'm totally with you in the black-box view and design by contract in general, but in this case the issue is related to jars being in the classpath (or temporary artefacts that shouldn't be running in production environment) so the implementation details/white box view is necessary to decide what to provision in the runtime environment. in your example, if it were to use JNI, i need to know it to set the proper permissions at the OS level

Comment: Eh, I dunno.  Someone somewhere decided that this tool was useful and the benefits that they accepted with using it came with the consequences of its use.  I think that someone would need to just approach it as wide-eyed as possible and say that yes, this does instrument and add extra things to our production bytecode with the point and benefit of it being ____, instead of the more dogmatic and myopic "eliminate all suspicious looking things, no matter the cost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) contains the following FAQ:  [Why are type annotations declared with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`?](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#faq-runtime-retention)

If you are using a tool that NPEs as a result of a missing annotation, that is a buggy tool.  Such a situation is not uncomon; for example, the JVM won't crash if it cannot find an annotation that is mentioned in a class file that it is running.

Comment: thank you very much @mernst. i missed the answer to my question from the FAQ. 
About the JVM not crashing, if qual is not in the runtime classpath a process *will* crash with just doing `getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0].getAnnotatedType()`. there are no libraries here doing weird stuff, just pure JDK. that generated the stacktrace in my OP. does this mean that qual jar is meant to be deployed in production environments?

Comment: actually, to be precise, the NPE was generated by hibernate-validator, but I traced it down to that call to `getAnnotatedType()` and i was able to reproduce the issue bypassing hibernate-validator completely with the code in the previous comment. the code seems harmless, not violating any JDK contracts